# R ggplot2 boxplot not properly shown when knitting html

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

tried a simply boxplot with ggplo2

```
ggplot(aes(x = quality, y = residual.sugar),data=data)+
  geom_boxplot(fill="#9999CC")+scale_y_continuous(limits =c (0,20))
```

when i exucute it in R itself, it looks like want it , like this:
[image]

but when i knit it to get my html file, it looks like this :

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix that? i am confused :(

Comment: I'm no expert here but the environment used to knit the html is different to the global one you might be talking about in the first picture. Have you followed your `.rmd` file through to make sure that `data` is actually referring to the data you want it to? Without being able to reproduce the error, this is difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Agree, make sure quality actually is present in the knitr environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely difference is that you forgot to make `quality` into a factor within your `rmd` file.

For example:

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(quality = sample(6:9,size=200,replace=TRUE),
                 residual.sugar = rnorm(200))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x = quality, y = residual.sugar),data=dd)+
   geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

```
dd2 <- transform(dd,quality=factor(quality))
ggplot(aes(x = quality, y = residual.sugar),data=dd2)+
   geom_boxplot()
```

[image]